# Selective counting up in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

For information, I asked the question in [www.clever-excel-forum.de](http://www.clever-excel-forum.de) and [www.ms-office-forum.net/](http://www.ms-office-forum.net/). I would like to achieve the following:

```
A1     A2     A3     A4      -> row 1
1      1      1      45      
              2      30      
              3      30
1      1      4      45
              5      30
                             ...
1      1    254      45
              1      30
              2      30
1      2      3      45
                             ... 
1    254    254      45
              1      30
              2      30
2      1      3      45
                            ...
3    189     12      45    -> up to approx row 250540
```

A2 should set a 1 from line 2 onwards in every three lines until a 254 was reached for the first time in A3. Then with the next setting (after 254 in A3) the 1 must be incremented and jump to 2 (A2). If the 254 in A2 is reached, it has to jump back to 1 and the 1 in A1 jumps to 2.

so far so good (from user: lupo1 from the ms-office-forum):

```
A1: =LET(n;250000;WAHL(SEQUENZ(;4);
WENN(REST(SEQUENZ(n);3)=1;KÜRZEN(SEQUENZ(n;;0;1/254^2)+1);"");
WENN(REST(SEQUENZ(n);3)=1;KÜRZEN(SEQUENZ(n;;0;1/254^1)+1);"");
REST(SEQUENZ(n;;0);254)+1;
INDEX({45.30.30};REST(SEQUENZ(n)-1;3)+1)))



WENN = IF, 
REST = MOD, 
SEQUENZ = SEQUENCE, 
KÜRZEN = TRUNC,
```

One thing doesn't work yet: Column A2 counts beyond 254, but should always jump back to 1 after 254.

Problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1334728-selective-counting-up-in-excel.html

```
    =LET(n,800000,CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,4),
IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(n),3)=1,1+TRUNC(SEQUENCE(n,,0,1/254^2)),""),
IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(n),3)=1,1+MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(n,,0,)/254),254),""),
1+MOD(SEQUENCE(n,,0),254),
INDEX({45,30,30},1+MOD(SEQUENCE(n)-1,3))))
```

or in my case for german:

```
    =LET(n;260000;WAHL(SEQUENZ(;4);
WENN(REST(SEQUENZ(n);3)=1;1+KÜRZEN(SEQUENZ(n;;0;1/254^2));"");
WENN(REST(SEQUENZ(n);3)=1;1+REST(GANZZAHL(SEQUENZ(n;;0;)/254);254);"");
1+REST(SEQUENZ(n;;0);254);
INDEX({45.30.30};1+REST(SEQUENZ(n)-1;3))))
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using the row() number as index, column C is just the remainder after division (modulus) by 254, offset by 1 (ie. 0..253 to 1..254):

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,254)+1
```

Column B is the quotient after integer division by 254 and column A the quotient after integer division by 254^2, both scaled to 1..254 with the modulus and offset by 1:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)=0,MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/254),254)+1,"")
```

and

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)=0,MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/(254^2)),254)+1,"")
```

The if statement just ensure the numbers are displayed on every third row.

[image]

Comment: One thing doesn't work yet: Column A2 counts beyond 254, but should always jump back to 1 after 254. How do I implement this in the giving code?

Comment: All three formulae have their final values inside MOD(..., 254)+1 with a possible range of 1 to 254 only. It is impossible to go beyond 254. Just double check your formulae.

Comment: In column C it counts from 1 to 254 and begins again. But in column B it counts every 254 one up (entered in every third column) but don't jumps back to one after 254. If you run the giving formula you'll see it.

Comment: Works fine for me. See picture in updated solution,

Comment: Why doesn't it work for me? Can you please post your formula. See picture in OP.

Comment: I double checked. My formula is exactly like the are written in my solution. See the first pic in my post. Note that my sheet does not have a header row and the data starts at row 1, but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Can you post the formula as a whole. Something is missing from me somewhere.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking for. It is not a single formula like lupo1's (called a spill formula, which can only be used in newer versions of excel) but rather three separate formulas, as posted in full in the solution. Copy them in order into A1, B1 and C1, then copy and paste down till row 250240.

Comment: Excel 365 says there are problems with the formula 2 and 3

Comment: Its probably a localisation problem. I copied the formula into google sheet no problem. Perhaps temporarily change your locale to english (UK) or (USA). Its probably colons that should be full stops etc.

Comment: How did you produced column D then?

Comment: Your formulas not working in Google Sheets either changed it  to English. Some things are missing, do I have to expand or adapt anything there?